# how to answer this recursion question and is there a big difference between it and loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion

What sequence of numbers would be printed by the following recursive
procedure if we started it with N assigned the value 1?

```
       procedure Exercise (N)
        print the value of N;
           if (N < 3) then (apply the procedure Exercise to the
          value N + 1);
        print the value of N.
```

the right answer suppose to be 123321 but i tried to answer it myself and i get it 1233

Comment: You forgot the second "*print the value of N*".

Comment: You can easily check this if you code and execute the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the last "*print the value of N* statement.

Say we invoke this with `Exercise(1)`. Then this means that it is evaluated as:

```
Exercise(1):
    print 1
    Exercise(1+1)
    print 1
```

this `Exercise(2)` call, will result in:

```
Exercise(2):
    print 2
    Exercise(2+1)
    print 2
```

the `Exercise(3)` call only results in two `print` statements, since the condition in the `if` statement is false, hence:

```
Exercise(3):
    print 3
    print 3
```

If we now perform substition, we get:

```
Exercise(1):
    print 1
        print 2
            print 3
            print 3
        print 2
    print 1
```

which will indeed yield the expected sequence.

Comment: my problem is in the substitution process i do not understand it i mean the last 3,2,1

Comment: We replace the `Excerise(1+1)` call (first code fragment) with its body (second code fragment), and then subsequently replace `Exercise(2+1)` with its body.

Answer (score 2):

For N=1

```
print 1;
if(N<3) --> Exercise (1+1);  //the condition is TRUE here. So the function will be called again for N=2
print 1;
```

For N=2

```
print 2;
if(N<3) --> Exercise (2+1); // Condition is again TRUE. So the function is called for N=3 
print 2;
```

For N=3

```
print 3;
if(N<3) --> Exercise (3+1); // Condition is FALSE here. So the function won't be called
print 3;
```

The structure will be like,

```
print 1;
  print 2;
    print 3;
    print 3;
  print 2;
print 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

When I want to know what an algorithm does, I often code and execute it.
Inserting `print` statements to trace the execution and data flow help show the call hierarchy.

```
indent = ""

def exercise(n):
    global indent
    indent += "  "
    print(indent, "ENTER", n)

    # Original assignment, with assigned output not indented
    print("REAL", n)
    if n < 3:
        exercise(n+1)
    print("REAL", n)

    print(indent, "LEAVE", n)
    indent = indent[2:]

exercise(1)
```

Output: here is a trace of the execution, with the assignment output labeled with "REAL".  Function enter and exit are trade and indented.

```
   ENTER 1
REAL 1
     ENTER 2
REAL 2
       ENTER 3
REAL 3
REAL 3
       LEAVE 3
REAL 2
     LEAVE 2
REAL 1
   LEAVE 1
```

---

Yes, this can easily be done with a pair of loops.  Whether this is a "big difference" depends on your judgment function.  For instance:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(n)
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(n)
```

If your processing of an individual case is trivial (such as `print(n)`), then this is easy.  When your iteration from one element to the next is trivial (such as `n+1`), then this is easy.  However, when either is complex, then recursion is often the more tractable way to describe and implement the process.